# Replacing bullets by image

Tags: html, css, list, background, html-lists

I want replace bullets by an image (which is about 40*40) i tried with list-style-image but i was unable to resize the image. so how to resize the image without affecting the text ?

Code :

```css
ul.no_bullets {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li.twitter {
  background-image: url("twitter.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<ul class="no_bullets">
  <li class="twitter"><b>Test 1</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li>
  <li class="twitter"><b>Test 2</b> – Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
    book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li>
  <li class="twitter"><b>Test 3r</b> – Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</li>
  <li class="twitter"><b>Test 4</b> –Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</li>
</ul>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This:

```css
ul.no_bullets{
    list-style-type: none;
}

.twitter img{
   width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="no_bullets">
        <li class="twitter"><img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAY1BMVEVQq/H///9ApvBHqPFEp/A8pPDs9f1bsPLg7/zx+P57vfT7/f/R5/vC3/n2+/622fjb7Pxtt/OXyvZVrvFks/K+3fnU6Pvn8v2o0vfJ4/qMxfWk0PeDwfSw1viVyfZxufMroO+odDONAAAGvElEQVR4nO2d65ayOgyGIWkREQUBD4jivv+r3OJhxhMKNGn5ZuX5NzNrCi+0zaFp8TxBEARBEARBEARBEARBEARBEARBEARBEARBEARBEIS/CaI6g4iub4UBBMij6pCs5qtkW0c5qD+lEmFSxQv/nmlZe/BXREK+3fjvSDMPvv2rnVs0AoryrbwLq/yDxtO/zpW9Ox2GmsQf9J01eu/7Kp4fTT32jgyHL/oaMv36jwj7tPkb6d3QT+GqeD/+ngnzx0sjYBWc/1J+Gaf9bmcREUvUVSd9Dfu714gQ/fTsgvB21Nb3J6QS9byzQN/fXl8W6sk2+Plt/Kb/DufU4JSyPfg2xTyygovZfOjXlLZCnaeEDV23h3Uvgb4/18tns5lRmgqcndsMqSRC2lOg78+ef7Gm7KNY31qlkQh9xmALpGPm7pGnFBJVZi7QL2in9t+GU/POjwWBQFrbhbu7pkPjpiFove/O7GkdUvUwbILcTKPq4qp9IfoRiHpJYDSeHvrCzPRPzAUerwJP/lsdhhSv8+URGsw3PU39GxaXSQYhzxqrSuG6LV8ukg2X+NpYT8JTEICgiiq83ArBK8T962XmQyXCp4C3C8l/Ot8f1tPbjVDYfXxnvjYDB2NuKHCepNO7H0nss4fbd5ea7Yc0/r6twQQ0VrHtruYDMn7QLejtCJXn1vrcg2Xv10jhzvwwM7TMvwrbg/GkZ07zQ1P9mVIJfHTangj6mUZzY3gnsCULN0Th8dOF4kkPjXrxqalebKjkNXzxsw7d03AEHtuVlDS2gC9PfpF1HI4YUQksSZNQHZIqwb6Txre+wxAOlIlSr5uZDvf6u0YkCJwaamKBHa1YsPvqAagVhb7ZkX49RneLyqcVfn64KiEQ+JzkJ6G7NzlffhqQJAprlhW1HhHBJsNWkRQJDL9iWVHrF9XFuxaRJJEFj8K+kfks3nnw6giQWAsmhQNC8/BwhKdX+S5bMBaFw/ytWZwVeF84QhE8cSkcPEks0qQuFJx04s8KzygVesooUx3ESbYvcgjNFWZcCtE4DXhiRvAOd2z1F50KJyyw56sw0f2XNTk4sgk8ddTp9+vzQ1mA8aJwQjCMjOHopFFxK/b4mLGxBIPjfYpbV5OLd0KXhhhMQB79Xv3leH92wZRziWT1IPcKL2ncWVlPAPTS8VgsOXrpb0QQlIe6divxwBHhU0QEZLCUlJIup5jCY/DHYAZvsAikKIChgsNYnEyE6do7ITGLQrJkPAFbnsjCtLyAEOpa7CuadPXdCKbgkLiCwgAOn+3MaLppwrVJRvcty+aCLYUxgqjpwp/P0aS0i9v3jCK6Z8wGez23uLDBmYXyPLpSmMHwOKU3xjDZHHg3VIJ7s8/bSQnKe03Z8M2kN4mOTQbnTHqT6Na1sbFzm2JL1mB4gt8XiQ6DYabQ8Jmu25PpmbLPMzd67FAmxcI8c0N5JAV4PZlZ09cA+cF6CpUt9m1Bwc6ycbSrrwF1nsX2vPGVFVPRMMm1hit5tLUm0do5LZj5i01almUcBjaHor1X+Lrb0g729DkKMJgDwwecJGxmVg/a0QTFd32xe5SQg2xGaM0jvWA/dcqdvHiBbntWNxKLluICyZ6C7kwdnFhGu5n3G5YC30dsLratLE8zFyzOp4GjU/Wg/n5vNCxdnaoHllIZlbuDEbWVpJudBGILYKGez4WhuEMt2QvbiU+76g0Cc86NcWdFVyDirOmrXA7CGwgZW6aG5GwdAlDVPD4c0fF+FCAsE/o5h628axhKF1VMqnLjfpJ5BkHny11NFB3THvtIB/5HVMwQuFbSAnpEb3CsAmFHlAQf4RhsQI8qVWx+uCYHqMn2CjkNJ1rRR7I0sf3EWgegoDvBy+DISTagoKux4ThbxxDUHz/e0BOWs3WMULijXKZJRhJMXEEFxxXlKvDC5GBbchBUtKKNJ8qxfCAIT+9OFdWaeA1/tnPVQ49eU3lx+QxTU30xiapVSh/Vl3SHPPYlCvxNGs8bynXIlFub7h1OMWihuPvg+ONVyuMtmi1z90ae0il7Jl2OwwZCwbN0H0bj0Negl/SFQmnU4bRMi8AkIbWB5ccDFt2gMKPK4U+3374Z5wiEI0VnjbsdWOsGBNyZ7SpJx/9dQwRvVw4ckussH9fs0gYCLLdhT5WbJHo+KHLcoPaO265rFekh8v7FL4sigvb21Tyctr7OxSbe7ib6X1T3wylg1MoronqbnMKPNE3DE+l6nlR1VHhKvzmn9d8Em4/5wi9/9au+giAIgiAIgiAIgiAIgiAIgiAIgiAIgiAIgiAIbvkfbf5iltAgrL0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="><b>Test 1</b> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li>
        <li class="twitter"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"><b>Test 2</b> – Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</li>
        <li class="twitter"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"><b>Test 3r</b> – Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</li>
        <li class="twitter"><img src="data:image/png;base64,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"><b>Test 4</b> –Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using li:before. See sample code below:

```
ul.no_bullets { list-style: none; }
ul.no_bullets li:before { content: url(twitter.png); }
```